# XSLT select first non missing value on different path

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML document along the lines of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<Document>
    <Person>
        <Name>Joe</Name>
        <Address>
            <Country></Country>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <Country>FR</Country>
        </Address>
        <Phone>
            <Number>11111111</Number>   
        </Phone>
        <Phone>
            <Number></Number>   
        </Phone>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Jim</Name>
        <Address>
            <Country>US</Country>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <Country>DE</Country>
        </Address>
        <Phone>
            <Number>1234567879</Number> 
        </Phone>
        <Phone>
            <Number>987654321</Number>  
        </Phone>
    </Person>
</Document>
```

What I want to do is transform it to this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <NewDocument>
        <xsl:for-each select="Document/Person" >
            <Person>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                </Name>
                <Addresses>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Address" >
                    <Address>
                       <Country>    
                          <xsl:value-of select="Country" />
                       </Country>
                    </Address>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Addresses>
                <Phones>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Phone" >
                     <Phone>
                        <Number>    
                           <xsl:value-of select="Number" />
                        </Number>
                        <PhnCtry>
                           <!-- TO DO -->
                        </PhnCtry>
                     </Phone>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Phones>
            </Person>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </NewDocument>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I would like is to populate the PhnCtry for each person with the FIRST NON MISSING address country for that person. Even better would be to only do this when number is not missing. I'm very new to XSLT so any help here would be hugely appreciated

Comment: What do you want to have happen when there are two non-Blank countries and two phone numbers (your second person)?  Could you post your desired output based on the input document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first non-missing address country for the Phone, you can use this expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="../Address/Country[. != ''][1]" />
```

Note that `..` gets the parent node,because you are positioned on `Phone` at this point.

Comment: Tim, I was thinking along these lines but putting the limiting selector on Address instead of country.  I don't know if the author will be happy with this though, as in his second example it will put 'US' as the PhnCountry for both phones even though DE is listed as a country as well.

Comment: I am happy with this as it does exactly what I asked for! Thanks :)